# Is there a way to see if the AMD fTPM mitigations from upstream kernel 6.2.6 are included in Ubuntu's upcoming kernel build?

Tags: kernel, amd-ryzen

I've been looking through https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+changelog and the related pages, and https://lists.ubuntu.com/archives/kernel-team/ but can't see anything definitive - but I'm also a total novice, so I might not know what I should be looking for.

I have an AMD Ryzen 5 laptop that was getting more and more heavily impacted by the fTPM stuttering issue running 6.1 kernels on Fedora, and there's no sign of an incoming fix from my laptop manufacturer - so I was trying to figure out if staying on Ubuntu would be an option going forward (I assume I'd be back to experiencing the issue if Ubuntu stuck with a 6.2.0 basis)?

Any guidance would be much appreciated!

Comment: As of right now Ubuntu only supports up to kernel 6.1 according to their web site.

Comment: The question as I see it cannot be answered; you've provided no OS/release details; Ubuntu 23.04 doesn't yet exist (it's currently Ubuntu *lunar*, and whilst it does use the 6.2 kernel - it's not on-topic on this site until it's been released).  Ubuntu 22.04 LTS will get the 6.2 kernel at 22.04.3 but that's still some distance into the future (*many months away*) with security fixes backported, not new features.  @David, my current kernel is `6.2.0-18-generic` & has been a couple of days since 6.1 upgraded to 6.2..

Comment: Note that this patch `tpm: disable hwrng for fTPM on some AMD designs` also have been backported to 6.1 LTS series, which it is a part of since `6.1.19` release. So you don't necessarily need 6.2.6 or later *(although of course a more modern kernel is always good to have)*.

Comment: @guiverc Sorry, didn't realize that questions about upcoming features were also off-topic (I had thought the link I followed on that implied that feature-related questions were OK, but I may have been reading too much into that).

Comment: @Hi-Angel Thanks, yeah my concern was if the Ubuntu 6.2 kernel being built was based on something before 6.2.6, since I'd think that would mean it wouldn't have that mitigation (unless there was something additional done to backport) - just trying to avoid a issue down the line, but perhaps that's a future problem best left to the future.

Comment: I think Ubuntu backports patches from later minor releases, but instead of increasing minor version it increases a patch-release version.